# How do you scale uniformly, using the Scale Tool in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When using Illustrator's interactive `Scale Tool`, how do you scale an object **uniformly**?

Comment: Yes, but the manual's information about the exact operation is actually plain wrong *when you have Smart Guides turned on*: Specifically the part saying "While using the Scale tool with the Shift key, start dragging at an angle of 45° horizontally or vertically but in an angle". This only counts for Smart Guides off, otherwise if using Shift, it will squash the object and only scale in horizontal or vertical direction.

Comment: ^ I should say, *sometimes*, not consistently. Which is why Shift should rather not be pressed when uniformly scaling with Smart Guides On (see gif in my answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer: If you have Smart Guides turned *off*, hold `Shift` while dragging. If you have Smart Guides turned *on*, holding Shift might render iffy results, sometimes squashing the object horizontally or vertically even if you're doing it right.

[image]

There are two gotchas when Smart Guides are On:

First, although arguably cryptically described in the manual, you have to drag along the *exact tangent relative to the reference point*, and then a guide appears indicating that you're scaling proportionally/uniformly. (Some people might've expected to be able to simply drag like when Smart Guides are off, but that won't workj until you've found that 'uniform line'.)

Secondly, and this is where the manual seems misleading: You should not hold Shift at all when dragging if Smart Guides are On. Reason being that, if you're dragging *from a certain angle* (this is getting complicated to describe, better see my included gif) your object will actually get squashed horizontally or vertically. This behavior is inconsistent, but annoying nevertheless. And simply *not* using Shift here, removes the issue. I.e. the opposite of what the manual is mentioning (Shift pressed).

Comment: Kind of confusing...`hold Shift while dragging an anchor point`.... erm.. you **don't** "drag anchor points" with the Scale tool.

Comment: @Scott you can drag anchor points, you dont have to offcourse but you can. Which is nbify if you want to match scale (and rotation)

Comment: @joojaa Hmm.. With the **Scale tool** I can't *drag* any anchor point.. I can *scale* an anchor point (and its handles) but I can't **drag** any anchor point. "Drag", to me, is associated with altering an anchors *position*.

Comment: @Scott so scaling does not alter position now? Ill shut up now ;)

Comment: @joojaa for an **anchor point** no. Scaling doesn't alter position. If you scale an **object** then, yes, its anchors will change position. To my point.. one does **not** "drag an anchor" with the scale tool - but if you scale an *object* yes the anchor positions will change, which *may* make it *appear* that the user is "dragging an anchor point" but the reality is they are not. It's no different than scaling with the Bounding Box.. you aren't "dragging anchors" even though their positions will change.

Comment: Admittedly, this distinction may be a bit overly specific. But there is a difference.

Comment: Its not actually smart guides that stop this but the alignment guides suboption overrides the drag.

Comment: @joojaa Interesting, where are those toggled?

Comment: In the preferences. This is important to know since alignment guides must be turned off at some point as your designs complexity exceeds a certain point.

Answer (score 2):

Depress and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and drag from a *general* corner area while using the tool.

If you drag closer to a side, you'll see the scale take on a more vertical or horizontal aspect, merely move the cursor (while still dragging) closer to a corner region.